# Multiple authenticators for different resources in dropwizard

Tags: authentication, dropwizard

Let's say I have two resources, /authenticate and /protected_resource. Authenticate verifies the user/password provided through the basic http authentication and, if successful, generates a jwt token. /protected_resource expects the token to be provided in the incoming request header as in oauth.
Can I install the two different authenticators/filters, "basic" and "jwt" and indicate that the basic one is for /authenticate and the jwt one is for /protected_resource?

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can.

*I haven't tried this specifically, but looking at the source code and according to my experience on playing around with AuthProviders, it should work.*

Just make sure that those authenticators return different classes.

```
environment.jersey().register(AuthFactory.binder(new BasicAuthFactory<User>(new UserAuthenticator(), "User authentication", User.class)));

environment.jersey().register(AuthFactory.binder(new OAuthFactory<Token>(new JwtAuthenticator(), "Jwt authentication", Token.class)));
```

and then in the resource classes:

```
@Path("/authenticate")
public String authenticate(@Auth User user){
   return jwtToken;
}

@Path("/protected_resource")
public FooDto getFoo(@Auth Token token){
   // do stuff
}
```

Comment: This solution doesn't really work. Inside of `ComponentBag.java` method `private boolean registerModel` returns false when registering second AuthFactory